# Is this considered an inline anonymous method?

Tags: java

```
 public void insert(final String key, final String value) throws Exception {
    execute(new Command(){
      public Void execute(final Keyspace ks) throws Exception {
        ks.insert(key, createColumnPath(COLUMN_NAME), bytes(value));
        return null;
      }
    });
  }
```

The body of new Command() looks like an inline method?

What is this called, I want to fully understand this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's an *anonymous inner class*. You're creating a class which derives from the `Command` class or just implements the `Command` interface. In this case you're only overriding one method, but you *can* override more - as well as having extra fields etc.

Java doesn't (currently) have anything which is quite the equivalent of a C# anonymous method, if that's what you were thinking of. An anonymous inner class is probably the closest thing to it though.

Comment: "Java doesn't (currently) have anything which is quite the equivalent of a C# anonymous method" or a Ruby anonymous method or a Python anonymous method or a Lisp anonymous method or a Javascript anonymous method or a...

Answer (score 5):

It's an [anonymous class](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/anonymousclasses.html).

`Command` is a previously defined interface or class, so this is equivalent to:

```
public void insert(final String key, final String value) throws Exception {
    class MyCommand implements Command { // or "extends Command"
        public Void execute(final Keyspace ks) throws Exception { 
            ks.insert(key, createColumnPath(COLUMN_NAME), bytes(value)); 
            return null; 
        } 
    }
    execute(new MyCommand());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it's an anonymous inner class.
In this case it's most likely an implementation of a Command interface or abstract class.

Answer (score 2):

As stated, it's an anonymous inner class.  You most often see this approach as a quick means to implement single-method interfaces.

Languages like Groovy and JavaScript use closures for this sort of thing.