# questions regarding the new keyword

Tags: java

I'm having difficulty understanding the concept of the new keyword. I know its used to instantiate objects; e.g. If I had a class called Superclass, I could create a object of that class by writing:

```
Superclass supeclassobject = new Superclass();
```

I understand that but what I dont understand is that this is also acceptable: 
E.g. if your were passing a Superclass object to a method which takes it as an argument, then the following would still work:

```
public void MethodTakingSuperClassObjectAsArugment (new Superclass()){
*CODE HERE*
}
```

I cant understand how that works. You haven't given a name to the object so how could you refer to it in the method? This makes sense to me:

```
Superclass sobject = new Superclass();
public void MethodTakingSuperClassObjectAsArugment (sobject){
    *CODE HERE*
    }
```

Comment: Objects don't have names.  Variables have names.  This is no different to `int x = 4; int y = 3; methodThatTakesAnInt(x + y);`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are Anonymous (inner) classes used in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/355167/how-are-anonymous-inner-classes-used-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Class definition inside method argument in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180222/class-definition-inside-method-argument-in-java)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Hello helloobj = new Hello(); Haven't i created a object of type Hello and gave it a name of helloobj?

Comment: No, `helloobj` is a reference variable, that refers to the object.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few misconceptions there.

First, there is a method *definition*, and then there is a method *invocation*.

Method definition is where you declare your method. You give it modifiers such as `public`/`private`/`protected`, a return type, a name, a list of parameters, an optional `throws` and a body:

```
public static int myInt( double myParameter ) {
    return (int)myParameter;
}
```

Here, the parameters must have names. Otherwise, you would not be able to refer to them in the body.

And then there is the method *invocation*. Within some other method, like `main`, you call your method:

```
int a = myInt( 15.7 );
```

You passed `15.7` without giving it a name. The value that you actually pass in a method *invocation* is called an *argument* as opposed to a *parameter*, which is the formal name and type given in the method definition.

If your method definition included a *parameter* of the type `SuperClass`, it would look something like:

```
public static void myMethod( SuperClass myParameter ) {
    ...
}
```

You can't use `new` in a *parameter* declaration. But when you *invoke* the method, and you have to pass an *argument* to it, you can use:

```
myMethod( new SuperClass() );
```

In the same way that you didn't need to give a name to your `15.7` before, you don't need to give a name to your new object now. When Java passes it to the method, the method sees it as the value of `myParameter`.

Your second misconception is about names of objects. Objects don't actually have names. But they do have *references*. You can refer to an object from a local variable, from a field or from inside another object. In those cases, you give the *reference* a name, not the object. So you can do something like this:

```
Superclass myVar = new SuperClass();
Superclass anotherVar = myVar;
```

What you have here is two reference variables. You assign a reference to a new object to `myVar`. And then you assign a reference to the same object to `anotherVar`. Both `myVar` and `anotherVar` refer *to the same object*. The object does not have a name. You can now do something like `myVar = null`. But the object will still exist, and you'll be able to access it through `anotherVar`.

Think of reference variables as arrows. You give the *arrow* a name, and you can point the arrow at any object of the appropriate type. Or you can assign `null` to it which means the arrow is not pointing at anything.

Back to the issue of parameters, sometimes you can see something like this:

```
myMethod( new SuperClass() {
   // Code here
} );
```

This is exactly the same as we did before. It's a method *invocation*. The code you see in the braces is not the code for `myMethod`. It is in fact the code for the new object. It's an anonymous class, which *extends* `SuperClass`, and has some of its own code in those braces. So the class is defined and an instance is created of it, and that instance - of an anonymous class extending `SuperClass` is what's being passed as an argument to `myMethod`. Inside `myMethod`, it can be accessed with `myParameter`. It's the same as writing this somewhere in the same file:

```
private class SomeClass extends SuperClass() {
    // Code here
}

And then calling `myMethod` like this:

myMethod( new SomeClass() );
```